# удаление объекта из массива объектов JS

Tags: javascript

Имеем массив объектов такого вида:

```
const array = [
{
  id: '...',
  type: '...',
  relations: {...},
  offices: {...},
  details: {address: 'Some Street 10', deleted: false}
},
{
  id: '...',
  type: '...',
  relations: {...},
  offices: {...},
  details: {address: 'Some Street 11', deleted: false}
},
{
  id: '...',
  type: '...',
  relations: {...},
  offices: {...},
},
];
```

И таких вложенных в массив объектов получаем достаточно много (я лишь привёл небольшой отрывок). Дальнейшая логика описана таким образом, что работа идёт с вложенным объектом **details** и его значениями, но среди 100 таких объектов есть 5-10 в которых отсутствует вложенный объект **details**, соответственно, при дальнейшей обработке массива объектов получаем ошибки в стиле **"Cannot read property 'address' of undefined** и поэтому задача стоит таким образом чтобы удалить все объекты из массива, в которых отсутствует вложенный объект **details**, т.к. они считаются не валидными и получить отфильтрованный массив объектов без "неправильных" объектов, как лучше отфильтровать данный массив?
На выходе должны получить:

```
const array = [
{
  id: '...',
  type: '...',
  relations: {...},
  offices: {...},
  details: {address: 'Some Street 10', deleted: false}
},
{
  id: '...',
  type: '...',
  relations: {...},
  offices: {...},
  details: {address: 'Some Street 11', deleted: false}
},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто фильтруем массив

```
let newArray = array.filter(obj => obj.details !== undefined)
```